# Is there any equivalent svn command for git fetch

Tags: git, svn, git-fetch

Anyway I have got some understanding about the differences between `git fetch`, `git pull` and `git merge`.

Now I want to know whether there exists an equivalent **svn** command for `git fetch` that copies the latest code from the remote repo and that doesn't merge the local branch.

Comment: With subversion, you don't have a local repo, do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't. In SVN you just update (`git pull` or `git fetch && git merge` in git) your code.